# How to get the result of a test in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir-webdriver

I want to get the result of a test in Rspec and use it in next tests. For example, if I want to test the button "add device", and then test "distribute" button, the first test should fail, then Rspec should skip the second "distribute" test. How can I do that?

Comment: RSpec will already do this. It stops on the first failure, and the entire example is considered a failure.

Comment: No ,Rspec test all things ,I want to skip the tests that depend on a failure previous test

Comment: @meagar: not if you set `aggregate_failures` on. I love this flag.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,but I want to skip the test not to stop the test process .@meagar

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get the result of a test in Rspec and use it in next tests.

Short answer: you must not want that.

Longer answer: test dependencies is one of the most horrible things a programmer can do. It's a hell to debug. If something fails, now you must debug the failing test AND all of the tests that ran before it! If you're into self-inflicting pain, go ahead. Otherwise, make each test independent and isolated. If test for "distribute" button needs a device, the device must be created in the setup step for that test.